# Collections.sort not working after overriding compare and compareTo

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable

The issue I'm having is using Collections.sort(linkedList); to try and sort a linked list full of points. I have already modified the compare and compareTo methods to fit the needs. as posted here, This snipped is for comparing the Y values in the list that way we can sort them.

```
 package points;

 import java.util.Comparator;

 public class CompareY implements Comparator<Point>
 {
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
         int equals = 0;

    if(p1.getY() > p2.getY())
    {
        equals = 1;
    }
    else if(p1.getY()< p2.getY())
    {
        equals = -1;
    }
    else if(p1.getY() == p2.getY())
    {
        //If the 'Y's' are equal, then check the 'X's'
        if(p1.getX() > p2.getX())
        {
            equals = 1;
        }
        if(p1.getX() < p2.getX())
        {
            equals = -1;
        }
    }
    return equals;
  }
}
```

My comparable (compare) method is within the main class, Point as shown here:

```
package points;

public class Point implements Comparable<Point>
{
    int x;
    int y;

public Point()
{
    //Blank default constructor
}
public Point(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


//Auto generated getters and setters
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int compareTo(Point o)
{
    int equals = 0;

    if(this.getX() > o.getX())
    {
        equals = 1;
    }
    else if(this.getX() < o.getX())
    {
        equals = -1;
    }
    else if(this.getX() == o.getX())
    {
        //If the 'X's' are equal, then check the 'Y's'
        if(this.getY()> o.getY())
        {
            equals = 1;
        }
        if(this.getY() < o.getY())
        {
            equals = -1;
        }
    }
    return equals;
  }

}
```

My issue lays within the Test class, where I try to call

```
Collections.sort((List<Point>) linkedList);
```

I get the error "The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (`List<Point>`"

Which I don't understand where it's coming from or why it is there if I did my methods.

TEST CODE:

```
package points;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Point;
public class Test
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int sizeLimit = 10;

    LinkedList<Point> linkedList = new LinkedList<Point>();

    //Populating our linkedList with random values.
    for(int i=0; i < sizeLimit; i++)
    {
        linkedList.add(new Point(rand.nextInt(10), rand.nextInt(10)));
    }

    System.out.println("original list");

    //Declaring our iterator to step through and print out our elements
    Iterator<Point> iter = linkedList.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }

    Collections.sort((List<Point>) linkedList);     

    }
}
```

Comment: post your test code.

Comment: Isn't that statement (collection.sort) is not using the compareTo? I thought it was since I'm not throwing it a comparator and even in the point class I implement comparable as well, overriding comapreTO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> import java.awt.Point;

You are importing the wrong `Point` class. The code does not use yours now.

If you remove that line, you will get the `Point` class from the current package.

Or you could do

> import points.Point;

Comment: Honestly, didn't even catch that. I thought it was necessary to use Points. Where would Points be located at? Or is it just a natural build without imports?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments the cast to List in the sort call is redundant. It sounds like you are using a List class other than java.util.List. Check your imports.

Failing that you should post your test code.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean there. I had it prior because I knew collections took an Object, with the error before hand I had to change it to a cast, thus began my issue.